# How to stop ajax loading request

Tags: jquery, ajax

test.php

```
 <select id="proc_id" class="multiselect custom processselect"   name="proc_id" style="display: none;">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

test.js

```
  var set_time =0;
var interval;
$('#proc_id').change(function(){
    set_time=$('#proc_id :selected').val();
    //alert((set_time));
    if(parseInt(set_time) > 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        set_time= set_time * 1000;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
             getFileProcessList(start_date);
             getResultInfoList(start_date); 
        }, set_time);
    } 
    else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

Based on the choosing time it will call the functions.In that functions I have ajax request.when I choose '1' ajax loads then if i choose '0' it stops calling the function but previously loaded ajax are loading.So I need to stop if previous ajax calls are loading when i choose '0' .

Comment: Is your execution going in the else part? verify once with console.log() / alert() statement.

Comment: Ya it is gng to else part.When i choose '0' it stop calling the functions and clearing the interval.The problem is if previous ajax call are there it is loading.

Comment: So, your previous ajax call may be in queue for execution, When the execution getting stopped?

Comment: Ya i need to stop that ajax request if is there in queue when i choose '0' .

Comment: Are you using Jquery ajax?

Comment: Ya I am using jquery ajax.

Comment: Can you prevent the selection until the ajax request return success/Failure.?Just a suggestion.

Comment: Ya ok thanks for new suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First count the number of selections..Use this one

```
var count = $('#proc_id option:selected').length;
```

it returns the number of selected options..based on this conditions do ajax..this what i understand from urs..isn't it?

You have noticed '1'..that means number of options or the value of the option?

Comment: The code is working fine.When i choose '1'  I am calling ajax request then if i choose the '0' without completing previous ajax request that time i need to abort the ajax call.

Comment: Jquery has inbuilt function to stop the ajax request on processing..set the ajax into one variable ex: (`var xyz= $.ajax({})`)..and use `abort()` function like `xyz.abort();`..based on your conditions

Comment: Ya i used abort it's not working.when i choose '1' first ajax is stoping when second comes.I need abort on choosing '0' .

Answer (score 0):

It's because `clearInterval` will only stop subsequent calls to the function passed in `setInterval` from firing. You need to store the jqXHR object returned from the AJAX call `var xhr = $.ajax({})` and then call `xhr.abort()` in an event handler to kill the request when the value is 0.

Comment: Ya i tried this                                                                        $(document).ready(
    var xhr;

    var fn = function(){
        if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
            xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/progress.ftl',
            success: function(data) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    };

    var interval = setInterval(fn, 500);
); but not working.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly i need to use the xhr.abort().

Comment: xhr needs to have a global scope then you can assign it the jqxhr object in your functions and call .abort in your else condition. Might be worth checking if it has a value before attempting to call abort()

Answer (score 0):

If one/ both your functions

```
getFileProcessList(start_date);
getResultInfoList(start_date);
```

has ajax request inside their definition then you can declare one / two global variables for example `var ajaxRequest1;`
Now, you can assign your ajax call to this variable as follows,

```
ajaxRequest1 = $.ajax({
 // your code
});
```

abort this request now where you are using **clearInterval()** as 
`ajaxRequest1.abort();` use this for all ajax request.

Comment: Ya tried that it is coming the error like abort() is not a function.

Comment: Which jquery version you are using? upgrade that if using old one.

Comment: ok i will upgrade to new version.I have to keep this ajaxRequest1.abort(); in the else part ?? where I am cleraring interval right ???

Comment: Yes, try once.@user123

Comment: I tried not executing code. I am using jQuery v2.1.4